# Hibernate not creating join table for Kotlin property with backing property

Tags: hibernate, jpa, kotlin

**::ORIGINAL::** (updated below)

I have the following (simplified):

```
@Entity(name = "Group")
@Table(name = "groups")
data class Group(
    @Column
    override val name: String,

) : CoreGroup {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    val id: Long = 0

    @Transient
    private val _users = mutableSetOf<User>()
    @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE])
    override val users get() = _users
}
```

The resulting table has the `name` and `id` columns as expected, but it does not create the join table I expect (`groups_users`).  If I remove the backing property, and just make `users` a normal property, it works as expected.

I've also tried doing `@get:@ManyToMany...` on the property, this has no effect.

If I put the annotation on the backing property instead:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE])
private val _users = mutableSetOf<User>()
override val users get() = _users
```

this creates the join table, but it is called `groups__users` (double underscore) and the foreign key column is called `_user_id`.  In the matching `User` class I also have to have the property reference the backing property, like so: `@ManyToMany(mappedBy="_users")`

I've tried using `@Column(name="user")` on the backing property, it seems to be ignored.

Why doesn't the actual property generate the join table?

**::UPDATED::**

It seems a cause of the problem is to do with using the annotation on methods rather than fields.  A simpler test case:

```
@Entity
class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private val id: Long? = null

    @OneToMany
    private val otherEntity: Set<OtherEntity> = setOf()

}
```

This generates a join table as expected.  However, this does not:

```
@Entity
class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private val id: Long? = null

    @OneToMany
    fun getOtherEntity(): Set<OtherEntity> {
        return emptySet()
    }
}
```

As I understand it, these should be equivalent?  The demonstrates the problem well, since in the original example using `@get:OneToMany` obviously puts the annotation on the generated get method.

Is there something wrong with my understanding of these annotations or Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I thought this was a Kotlin issue, but found I had the same problem when I wrote this in Java.  Eventually I found that you cannot mix field and method annotations for Hibernate.

It's in the documentation (RTFM...):

> #### [2.2.2.2. Access type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e535)
>
> By default the access type of a class
>   hierarchy is defined by the position
>   of the @Id or @EmbeddedId annotations.
>   If these annotations are on a field,
>   then only fields are considered for
>   persistence and the state is accessed
>   via the field. If there annotations
>   are on a getter, then only the getters
>   are considered for persistence and the
>   state is accessed via the
>   getter/setter. That works well in
>   practice and is the recommended
>   approach.
>
> > **Note**
> >
> > The placement of annotations within a class hierarchy has to be consistent
> >     (either field or on property) to be
> >     able to determine the default access
> >     type. It is recommended to stick to
> >     one single annotation placement
> >     strategy throughout your whole
> >     application.

For my particular issue, using a backing property in Kotlin then I must use the `@Access` annotation like so:

```
@Transient
private val _users = mutableSetOf<User>()
@get:ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE])
@get:Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
override val users get() = _users

private fun setUsers(users: Set<User>) {...}
```

Unfortunately, this means I must implement a private setter.